# AWS Dynamo DB: High read latency using query on GSI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamo db table which contains Date, City and other attributes as the columns. I have configured GSI with Date as the hash key. The table contains 27 attributes from 350 cities recorded daily.

```
|   Date     |  City      | Attribute1  | Attribute27|

+------------+------------+-------------+------------+

| 25-06-2020 | Boston     | someValue   | someValue  |

| 25-06-2020 | NY         | someValue   | someValue  |

| 25-06-2020 | Chicago    | someValue   | someValue  |

+------------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

I have a Lambda proxy integration setup in API Gateway. The lambda function receives a 7 day date range as the request. Each of the date, in this range is used query the dynamodb (using query input) to get all the items for a given day. The result for each day is consolidated for a week, and is then sent back as a JSON response.
The latency seen in POSTMAN is around 1.5s, after increasing the lambda memory to 1024MB (Even though, only 76MB is being consumed).

Is there any way to improve the performance? The dynamo db is already running in On-Demand Capacity.

Comment: If your operations are ready intenstive, you can setup DAX cache cluster in front of your DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you are using parallel queries or not.

If not do so.

You also don't say what cloudwatch is showing for Query latency, as mentioned by Marcin, DAX can help reduce that.

You also don't mention what cloudwatch is showing for lambda execution.  There's various articles about optimizing lambda.

Whatever's left is networking...not much you can do about that..one piece to consider is reusing [Db connections in your lambda](https://www.jeremydaly.com/reuse-database-connections-aws-lambda/)